# make height of a div the same of the absolute div inside it

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, css-position

I have a div (with a relative position) which has two divs inside. One of those has absolute positioning and I've noticed that it goes out the div's parent margins.

I'd like to make the height of the div parent (and also of the other non-absolute positioned div) the same as the one of the absolute positioned div.

Basically I would like the container div and all of its divs inside to adapt their height on the highest height taken.

Can you help me understand how to make it?

```css
.container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: blue;
}
.element {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 50px 150px 90px 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 30px;
  position: relative;
  font-family: 'helvetica','arial',sans-serif;
}
#element-1 {
  background-color: beige;
}
#element-2 {
  background-color: darkGreen;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="element"  id="element-1">
    <h1>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="element" id="element-2">
    <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: why you need absolute then?

Comment: I'm using it because I would like to have a certain transition since I'm modifying the height and width of  the divs through javascript

Comment: You dont need "position: absolute" to modify height and width of an element in HTML, even if its dynamic. Css transitions or just plain css will work fine.

Comment: I know, it's just to make the transition look a certain way. I feel leave the position:relative the animation makes a "jump" when I change the size of the divs

Comment: better focus on your main problem which is related to the animation you want to achieve. You are probably doing it the wrong way. I also agree that you don't need absolute for width/height animation

Comment: Here's the jQuery code you want: https://jsfiddle.net/95zsngwf/